# validate a Sentence or a paragraph

Tags: regex, validation, expression

I am trying to validate a sentence. It starts with alphabets, contains numbers and special characters like '-,() and may end with : or . I am trying to find an expression that can match the following pattern.

```
            I'm trying to-achieve such(this), kind of pattern:
```

I have tried using ^[a-zA-Z]+([ '/-]{0,1}+([()]{0,1}[,]{0,1})+[a-zA-Z0-9.]+[:]??)+$ , but am facing a problem at getting ',' after a closing ')' followed by space.

Can someone please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You have one unescaped caracter `/`

Comment: i have included \ before /. but it is not being displayed

Comment: Yeah I just experience this when commenting :) just double it

Comment: Can you explain the pattern more precisely? Your example includes features such as balanced parentheses and I don't know if that is important to you. Is `FO-O'))123))::::.` also an example?

Comment: The patterns are like   (1)  Abc def(ghi), jkln'm no-pqr stu/vwx 123 yz:        (2) Abc def(ghi), jkln'm no-pqr stu/vwx 123 yz................I want it to support only '), ' and ')/(' but not other combinations like '/- ' or other such.

Answer (score 2):

Let's make sure I understand what you're going for:

1. Your regex will match an entire sentence, meaning *any string that starts with a letter of the alphabet and ends with a colon or period*.
2. This sentence may contain numbers and special characters; really any character *except for a colon or period,* which would signal the end of the sentence.

If so, then all you need is this:

`^[A-Za-z][^\.:]*[\.:]$`

`^` matches the beginning of the string.

`[A-Za-z]` matches any letter of the alphabet, upper- or lower-case.

`[^\.:]*` matches 0 or more characters of any kind as long as they are not a colon or a period.

`[\.:]` matches a colon or a period.

`$` matches the end of the string.

This will only work if the string you're matching is the sentence and nothing else. To match a sentence that is part of a larger string, try removing the `^` at the beginning and the `$` at the end, and using the `/g` (multiple matches) tag if it meets your needs.

Comment: Good work, +1, but I don't think the OP realizes that's what his stated requirement boils down to.